# Mail being sent in spite using random port number using java mail API

Tags: java

I have created a servlet using the custom mail server API where I am receiving the parameters from front end.When I am sending random numbers for the "mail.smtp.port",the mails are still being sent.**I just want to know if the server is using the default port value for random numbers that are given as input,is it doing the same when a valid input is given?If yes,what step should I take?**

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

    final String USERNAME = request.getParameter("userName");
    final String PASSWORD = request.getParameter("password");


    String host = request.getParameter("hostSMTP");
    String port = request.getParameter("portSMTP");
    String type = request.getParameter("typeSMTP");     
    String fromName = request.getParameter("name");
    String from = request.getParameter("from");
    String to = request.getParameter("to");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String body = request.getParameter("body");


    System.err.println(host);
    System.err.println(port);
    System.err.println(type);
    System.err.println(fromName);
    System.err.println(from);
    System.err.println(to);
    System.err.println(subject);
    System.err.println(body);



      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put("mail.smtp."+type+".enable", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

        Authenticator authenticate = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticate);

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);


            try {
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from,fromName));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));



            message.setSubject(subject);

            message.setSentDate( new Date());

            message.setText(body);

            System.out.println("object==>"+message);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.err.println("Mail Sent.");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Try enabling debug logs and see what's happening - properties.put("mail.debug", "true")

Comment: Thank you Andy.I added the line above and provided with the inputs and it is showing the following things in logs
{mail.debug=true, mail.smtp.port=465, mail.smtp.SSL.enable=true, mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com, mail.smtp.auth=true}

Comment: If you are submitting the values to the servlet from a javascript, just make sure you haven't set any static value(like 465) there in the script.

Comment: I am sending the values dynamically from an input box.There is no static values.And when I gave the alternate smtp port as 123,which is invalid,the mails are still being sent.The mails are also being sent if I am leaving the port value as blank.learningloop.